# What does this error message mean?

Tags: windows-10, amazon-web-services, python3

I use Python 3.7 and try to install the amazon ECS-CLI.

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker<4.0,>=3.3.0->docker-compose<1.22.0,>=1.21.2->awsebcli) (from versions: 219, 223)
No matching distribution found for pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker<4.0,>=3.3.0->docker-compose<1.22.0,>=1.21.2->awsebcli)
```

Comment: Perhaps try running `pip install pypiwin32` but I see https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/#history and 223, not sure if it's compatible with Python 3.6 but read up on it, test, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what it says. I can't be installed because certain components are not available to meet all the necessary criteria.

In particular there is no version of pypiwin32 available for Windows and Python > 3.6.

Comment: And therefore I must downgrade python to 3.6 (?) to use awsebcli (?)

Comment: Not necessarily. You probably should just check the requirements for that package and if [that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) would be the applicable documentation it would seem you probably need Python 3.6 or earlier. But you haven't really included what command you ran to get that error so it might be something different as well.

Comment: The docker-py project currently does not support Python 3.7. Python 2.7.x does work. I have not tested 3.6. https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1926